# Jenkins and GIT - Start build job on webhook event WITHOUT pulling source from GIT

Tags: git, jenkins, github, gitea

Short question: Is it possible to start a build job (remote SSH shell script) when event comes through webhook WITHOUT jenkins pulling source from GIT repo?

Little background: Our organization has GITEA and JENKINS set up and they all work beautifully. No config problems, no errors or anything. Just when an event comes through webhook, jenkins pulls the code from repo before it runs remote script through ssh. The remote script also pulls source from git repo. We would like to avoid fetching the source code twice, most preferably from jenkins. So basically - on GIT push event we would like jenkins to run remote shell script. No git pull/fetch/clone... just ssh.

Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: i don't think so, but if the script uses git it shouldn't fetch the same commits twice, git would just realize it's already uptodate and call it day

Comment: the problem is that jenkins and target script are not on the same host, they are on different virtual machines. That means jenking fetches git source on first VM and then executes a remote script via ssh on other VM, which again fetches source from git (which is as it was originally intended).